# "Welcome back, you have been logged in" blocks the search box at the top

Tags: feature-request, notification-bar

If you are logged in one of SE sites and you go to another, you will be automatically logged in and get a "Welcome back XXX, you've been logged in. Click here to refresh the page" message.

These messages by themselves are useful and are appreciated. However, they are right on the top bar, forcing you to take action (refresh the page, or click to dismiss), before you can do anything.

This is not always necessary.

For example, sometimes I come to meta just to search for `[faq] accept rate` and get the link to the first post (for you know what). I could bookmark the page, but that's just an example and is not the point of this post.

Obviously, if I finish writing my search query, press enter and click the first link, that page would already have me logged in. So it was not necessary for me to "refresh" the page the first time. However, giving a message right on top of the form I am writing to (even though the form is not disabled, again not the point), is not *nice*.

My request is to present such messages in a nicer way. Put it somewhere that is visible, but doesn't force me to make it go away, before I can use the top bar.

Comment: People who downvote, do you mind saying why you disagree? Do you actually like it when it forces you to refresh? It's annoying even with a fast internet, but have you ever considered that in a country such as Iran (I'm not there anymore), it would take at least 5~10 seconds to refresh any page? What benefit do you see in the current behavior of that particular message?

Comment: I have noticed sometimes, when I'm writing an answer sometimes i'll see the grey "there have been new answers" bar, and sometimes the orange

Comment: @Servy Shahbaz specifically said "do you mind saying why you disagree" and has not edited.

Comment: @SamIam, the "there have been new answers" are actually very useful. Sometimes it saves me the trouble of repeating something someone else has already written. Besides, that notification doesn't interrupt your work. The one I'm talking about here does.

Comment: I edited your post title because I think that's your request. I originally downvoted based on the sentiment that "all these rare notifications are bad!" because they are exceedingly rare. But the specific case in the title, I can understand, though.. still very rare.

Comment: @JeffAtwood, I edited the body correspondingly. But I would like you to know that this is a "user-friendly-ness" thing. Forcing the user to do something unnecessary is not nice. If the notifications appear in a different way that doesn't interfere with the rest of the webpage (but of course not in the ads area (on the right), where no one looks at), it would be great :)

Comment: @JeffAtwood, one other solution, which is probably harder to code, is to be able to click it to go away, and it would show that you are logged in without refreshing the page. If that is done, then perhaps the whole notification could also go away.

Comment: @jeffatwood: The "Welcome back, you have been logged in" message used to be rare. I never got them until the recent upgrade or datacenter move or whatever it was. Now I get them every time I visit any of the stack exchange sites. What happened? What can I do to have SE remember me?

Comment: @HeadofCatering, could be a coincidence. Have you changed a setting in your browser or something? I get it all the time since I have my browser clean all cookies on exit, so I log in every time I open the browser.

Comment: This started happening to me on different machines and different browsers all at the same time. I do use Ninite to keep the browsers up to date on all the machines, so it's possible Ninite configured something that is causing the behavior.

Comment: @HeadofCatering, you could try asking this as a separate question!

Comment: I find these popovers incredibly annoying. I search for something in Google which might lead me to stack overflow. The actual result isn't quite what I want so I want to search the site. Instead of a search box, I see a popover which is completely useless to me. Instead of doing what it commands me to do (Click here), I hit back and see if Google is better at refining my search.

Comment: @DenisHennessy, exactly. It's an obvious thing that a pop up (and a useless one at that) shouldn't block the UI. I don't understand how the SE designers don't see that.